# XSLT parameters from C# (XML to XML)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I need to transform an XML file to another XML filtered. I want to use XSLT/C# to do this operation.
My source code in C# will execute the XSLT file with a list of parameter (I'm using XslCompiledTransform class).

My question is : how in XSLT language I can parse all parameters transmited from the C# to filter the output XML file.

Example : a list of car

```
 <cars>
    <car brand="Audi" model="A4/>
    <car brand="Audi" model="A6/>
    <car brand="Audi" model="A7/>
    <car brand="Volvo" model="V40" />
    <car brand="Volvo" model="V60" />
    <car brand="Honda" model="Civic" />
    <car brand="Mercedes" model="Class E" />
 </cars>
```

a simple XSLT with brandsSelect parameter

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
     <xsl:param name="brandsSelect"></xsl:param>
     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>        
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my C# source code, I populate my variable : 
brandsSelect = Volvo, Honda

Expected result :

```
 <cars> 
    <car brand="Volvo" model="V40" />
    <car brand="Volvo" model="V60" />
    <car brand="Honda" model="Civic" /> 
 </cars>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you asking "how do I supply the value of `brandsSelect`?" ? Or are you asking "how do I apply the filter in the xslt?" ?

Comment: How do I apply the filter in the xslt :)

Comment: Here is an example about using params: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-parameters but how to filter is probably a XSL-only question. Haven't done that before.

Comment: Hm, I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950734.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do (in XSLT 1.0 which is what XSLTCompiledTransform implements) is to do a string test to see if the parameter "contains" the `brand` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="cars">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="car[contains($brandsSelect, @brand)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this will fail if one brand happens to be a substring of another (For example, if "Laudi" was brand as well as "Audi"

So, to make it robust, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="brandsSelect">Volvo,Honda</xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="brandMatcher" select="concat(',', $brandsSelect, ',')" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match="cars">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="car[contains($brandMatcher, concat(',', @brand, ','))]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is important to note, the value of the `brandsSelect` should not contain any spaces between the brands, only commas.